# combine three parts

Tags: c#, .net

Path.combine can only combine two string, is there a qucik way to combine three and four strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade to .Net 4.0, which adds the [overloads you're looking for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx).

---

If you're stuck in .Net 3.5, you can call `Path.Combine` multiple times.

If you have an `IEnumerable<string>`, you can write

```
string path = strings.Aggregate(Path.Combine);
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize they added foldl to .Net 4.0.  Nice.

Comment: @jtdubs: It's been present since C# 3.0.

Comment: @SLaks: `foldl` is left fold in functional programming. It's the same as `Enumerable.Aggregate` in C#. You'll also see `foldr` which is the same as `Enumerable.Reverse().Aggregate`. The notation comes from Haskell.

Comment: LINQ contains a number of elements from functional programming under different names.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a C# programmer, but something like

```
string s = Path.Combine("str1", Path.Combine("str2", Path.Combine("str3", "str4")));
```

Seems obvious.

Answer (score 2):

If you can upgrade to .NET 4.0 it has what you are looking for.

Otherwise:

```
public string Combine(IEnumerable<string> strings) {
    return strings.Aggregate((x, y) => Path.Combine(x, y));
}
```

and

```
public string Combine(params string[] strings) {
    return Combine((IEnumerable<string>)strings);
}
```

Comment: @SLaks: Wow. Didn't know about that overload. Thanks!